# Color bleeding when piping

Tags: whipped-cream, decorating, coloring

I'm trying to mix color in whipped cream for decorations, but it always bleeds the color down to my white cake coat foundation. Can somebody help?

Answer (score -1):

**Make sure your cake fondant isn't too runny**.

It might be a good idea to **let the fondant on the cake set for a few hours** before topping on the whipped cream, in order to harden the foundation to prevent colors from bleeding in.

*Here is a thread of comments that focuses on the issue with bleeding colors from whipped cream: [Keep Colors From Bleeding?](https://www.cakecentral.com/forum/t/20389/keep-colors-from-bleeding)*

Comment: I only used whipped cream for both cake coats and decorations. 